# Get bluetooth button input with php

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth, web-server, php

I'm new to raspberry development but I'm experienced with the web languages (PHP,html5,javascript and css). I want to develop a simple counter that will be increment when the pression of a wireless button is done, I'm thinking to use a pi with a cheap bluetooth button to handle the system. The GUI will be a standard `index.php` page. As I know about the raspberry, it can manage an apache server and this is great, but my doubt is about the input provided by the button. How I can manage it to let the php take the input provided and then increment the number?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but I doubt that it has the system-access necessary to perform this task.

Comment: I read on the raspberry forum that using the `shell_exec()` will give the ability to run scripts that command the various hardware connected to the raspberry. I don't know if there is any script that will manage the input from a wireless buttun, but I want to go deeper on this argument.

Comment: I can write up a script for you, either .py or .sh